# Xcode archiving issue (codesign exit 1)

Tags: xcode, xcode8, codesign

I'm new to using xcode and am having a very hard time figuring out why my archive wont go through, this image below is the error message I'm receiving. Any input on a solution would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKBz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dylan Welcome onboard I remember the first day I started and made many mistakes in order for me to be as good as Im now. To get to your question I still get this error from time to time usually i will do an Xcode clean or delete my derived files this usually solve the problem. If that does not work you want to start to break point in order to find out what is causing the issue.